# Testing xPage application using jMeter

Tags: jsf, testing, xpages, jmeter, icefaces

Does anybody know how to do stress testing for xPage application using jMeter?

I tried to find a parallel with JSF test and ICE faces (http://tol8.blogspot.com/2010/12/load-andor-stress-test-of-icefaces-web.html), but without success.

I don't know which variables should I declared as Regular Expression Extractor.

I have used Recording Controller but that's not enough.

Here is example parameters from my post:

- path:

  ```
  ${path}?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id3%3AcallbackInfo%3AtabPanel1%3A_id47%3ApanelResultUpdate
  ```
- parameters (name/value/encode/incluse equals):

  ```
  view:_id1:_id3:callbackInfo:tabPanel1:_id47:txtIDClient     true    true       
  view:_id1:_id3:callbackInfo:tabPanel1:_id47:txtCompanyName      true    true    
  view:_id1:_id3:callbackInfo:tabPanel1:_id47:inputText1      true    true    
  view:_id1:_id3:callbackInfo:tabPanel1:_id47:rbState 1   true    true       
  view:_id1:_id3:callbackInfo:tabPanel1:_id47:inputHiddenKeyPress     true    true
  $$viewid    !dgb336swku!    true    true
  $$xspsubmitid   view:_id1:_id3:callbackInfo:tabPanel1:_id47:eventHandler1   true    true
  $$xspexecid     true    true    $$xspsubmitvalue        true    true
  $$xspsubmitscroll   0|0 true    true    
  view:_id1   view:_id1   true    true
  ```

Thanks.

Comment: Please, update your question, what tests you want to run, what you mean by "that' not enough' and so on.

Comment: At Lotusphere 2012, Julian Robichaux and Mark Myers did a session on unit tests (SHOW114), also with XPages. They covered jUnit as well as Jasmine. You might want to take a look at the slidedeck: http://www.londondevelopercoop.com/ldc.nsf/files/Ls12/$file/SHOW114.pdf

Comment: I would be very interested in your results. If you need assistance ping me on skype (notessensei).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only post parameter that You need to extract on first request is the $$viewid. This will give You the ability to access the right component tree in following request.

Of course You should make sure that HTTP cookie manager is in right place (otherwise You wont be able to keep the servlet and notes sessions)

It worked for me so with this two things in mind You should be able to run the stress tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to find a solution. Like you said only thing I need to extract is $$viewId (using XPath Extractor - XPathQuery: //input[@type="hidden"][@name="$$viewid"]/@value)